# Excel macro copy same entries once in another sheet paper

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm really new to VBA Excel.

Let's say I have paper 1 with in column A many alert types, and column B the place where it happened (I'm working for a security company). What I need to do is read column A and then column B; if there is more than 50 times same column A value, then put it in paper 2 without putting it X number of times, only when column B is different.

Example :

```
Col A :                                  Col B : 
Alert named 1 (50 times repeated)        Chicago
Alert named 1 (50 times repeated)        Tunis
Alert named 1 (50 times repeated)        Tunis
Alert named 1 (50 times repeated)        Tunis
Alert named 2                            ohoa
```

In paper 2 :

```
Col A :           Col B :
Alert named 1     Chicago
Alert named 1     Tunis
```

Comment: any reply please ?

Comment: Don’t be impatient.  Super User has users around the world, and that means many time zones.  Some of us have lives other than Super User.  It might take days (or longer) to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question?  For example, do you mean that cell `A2` says `Alert named 1 (50 times repeated)`?  Or do cells `A2` through `A51` say `Alert named 1`?  Is worksheet 1 guaranteed to be sorted?  etc…

Comment: It's an example for A2 cell, when we have 50 of same cell content, and they are not sorted

Comment: So, for example, cell `A2` could say `Alert named 1 (30 times repeated)` and cell `A42` could say `Alert named 1 (40 times repeated)`, with the same location, while cells `A3`-`A41` have other alerts and other locations?

Comment: Yes, but then in total, we would have 70 repeat, which means that condition had happened in that case (pass over 50 times repeat)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  You should probably [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/642076/edit) the question to include this information.  My point is that the data can be a lot messier than your example shows, and that complicates what the function is required to handle.

Comment: If you're just interested in all possible unique combinations of Col A and Col B, a pivot table could give you that. For your data, it would list 3 entries (collapsing `Alert named 1 (50 times repeated) | Tunis` into a single entry.

Comment: @Werner: Read the comments: How would your suggestion combine the row that has `Alert named 1 (30 times repeated) | Tunis` with the row that has `Alert named 1 (40 times repeated) | Tunis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible to do with just a formula. Here's a macro I wrote and tested that will list any `Alert Type` along with the `Location` on `Sheet 2` if it occurs `50 times in a row` in `Sheet 1`.

Open `VBE` <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, insert a new `Module 1` and copy and paste the below code.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

    ReDim arr(0) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arr(i - 1) = ws1.Range("A" & i) & "^" & ws1.Range("B" & i)
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    Next i

    RemoveDuplicate arr
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)

    Dim j As Long, cnt As Long: cnt = 0
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If arr(i) = ws1.Range("A" & j) & "^" & ws1.Range("B" & j) Then cnt = cnt + 1
        Next j
        If cnt > 50 Then
            ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Split(arr(i), "^")(0)
            ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Split(arr(i), "^")(1)
        End If
        cnt = 0
    Next i
    ws2.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDuplicate(ByRef StringArray() As String)
    Dim lowBound$, UpBound&, A&, B&, cur&, tempArray() As String
    If (Not StringArray) = True Then Exit Sub
    lowBound = LBound(StringArray): UpBound = UBound(StringArray)
    ReDim tempArray(lowBound To UpBound)
    cur = lowBound: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(lowBound)
    For A = lowBound + 1 To UpBound
        For B = lowBound To cur
            If LenB(tempArray(B)) = LenB(StringArray(A)) Then
                If InStrB(1, StringArray(A), tempArray(B), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next B
        If B > cur Then cur = B: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(A)
    Next A
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(lowBound To cur): StringArray = tempArray
End Sub
```

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or `Run` » `Run Sub` and check out the results in `Sheet 2`